# The difference between (setq shell t) and (shell . t)

Tags: quote

Upon configuring babel, encounter such syntax

```
(require 'ob-ipython)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((ipython . t)
   (python . t)
   (shell . t)
   ;; other languages..
   ))
```

What's the difference between `(setq shell t)` and `(shell . t)`

Comment: Look up "dotted pairs" for more information.

Comment: In this instance `(setq shell t)` is code (setting a variable) and `(shell . t)` is data, so other than the text containing many of the same characters, there's barely *anything* similar about them.

Comment: could you please transmit the comment to answer. @phils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(setq shell t)` would be *code*, setting the variable `shell` to the value `t`.

In the example in the question `(shell . t)` is part of a larger list of *data* being passed to the function `org-babel-do-load-languages`.